# backbone.js: Prevent <th> from disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I just got started on using backbone.js. I have a view `ListingListView` that refreshes a table with new content when `fetch()` is called.

**Problem:** This table contains some `<th>` elements. If I were to do a `$(this.el).empty();` and `this.render()` during the update of the table contents, the `<th>` elements will be removed. How can I prevent this? I want the `<th>` elements to remain. Thanks!

**JS Code**

```
// Views

window.ListingListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#listing_list table',

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('reset', this.refreshList, this);
        this.model.bind('add', function(listing) {
            $(this.el).append(new ListingListItemView({ model: listing }).render().el);
        }, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(listing) {
            $(this.el).append(new ListingListItemView({ model: listing }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },

    close: function() {
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).empty();
    },

    refreshList: function() {
        $(this.el).empty();
        this.render();
    }
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="listing_list">
    <table class="table table-bordered table table-striped">
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Beds</th>
        <th>Baths</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not very elegant but you could just use jquery to bung them in where they're needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add some structure to your table, using `thead` and `tbody`:

```
<div id="listing_list">
    <table class="table table-bordered table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Beds</th>
        <th>Baths</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And target the `tbody` in your `render` and `refreshList` functions:

```
render: function() {
        var $tbody=this.$("tbody"); // or $(this.el).find("tbody")

        _.each(this.model.models, function(listing) {
               $tbody.append(new ListingListItemView({ model: listing }).render().el);
        }, this);

        return this;
},

refreshList: function() {
    this.$("tbody").empty();
    // or $(this.el).find("tbody").empty() if you prefer
    this.render();
}
```

Notes:

- don't forget you can use a collection as a special option instead of a model : http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor It could be a bit clearer in the end.
- Backbone proxies Underscore functions on collections, `_.each(this.model.models...` can be written as `this.model.each` (`this.collection.each` if you apply the note above)